# Intermittent IIS8/Visual Studio 2010 debugging issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis-8

I have an intermittent issue when trying to debug local IIS sites.

Visual will hang and eventually displays the error:

> The web server did not respond in a timely manner. This may be because another debugger is already attached to the web server

If I wait a minute and hit "Start Debugging" again it will work (sometimes I may get the error several times but it eventually works).

There is nothing in the Event Viewer around the times I try to debug.
The app pool is .net V4.0 Integrated.
I am running Windows 8 Pro with IIS 8 and Visual Studio 2010.
Also its a site using EpiServer 6 R2.

I have tried IISReset, stopping/starting the site, closing and reopening Visual, rebooting my machine. None of that seems to make a difference, its hit and miss whether the solution will debug or not.

Once the solution is debugging, it runs fine without issue. Until I stop debugging and try and start debugging again.

The site runs fine in all other aspects, its only when I try to debug.

Answer (score 0):

So... I never fixed this issue, but have since upgraded to a solid state drive. So I now have a fresh install of Windows 8 Pro and Visual and the issue has not resurfaced.